# Entity Framework Split Table Delete

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

I'm using EF 4 STE's to model an Attachment object. The **Attachment** contains a Name, Description, Date, and most importantly Data (`byte[]`). To optimize loading, I don't want to retrieve the Data property until it's absolutely necessary, i.e. when the user clicks `Download` from the client.

In an effort to follow this approach, I used the table-splitting technique described [here](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef-table-splitting-ndash-the-opposite-of-entity-splitting/). I split my **Attachment** table up into **Attachment** (Name, Description, Date) and **AttachmentData** (Data). It's a 1-to-1 relationship in my EF model. Everything works great until I try to delete an **Attachment** without the **AttachmentData** (i.e. `attachment.AttachmentData == null`). I get the following exception:

> Invalid data encountered. A required relationship is missing. Examine StateEntries to determine the source of the constraint violation.

I saw a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595795/delete-entity-in-ef4-without-loading-the-entire-entity), but I can't seem to make it work with STE's and the `ApplyChanges` extension method.

Right now my data access code is simple: I call context's `ApplyChanges()` followed by `SaveChanges()`.

I've tried a simple delete SQL function and mapped it to both entities and that actually worked; however it broke the insert. I can't seem to map an insert function for all properties to both entities.

Any ideas on some other options I can try? Can the relationship between Attachment and AttachmentData be optional? When I make it 1 to 0+, I get a mapping error saying that `Their primary keys may collide`.

Open to any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is similar to linked question but you must use specific feature of STEs - `ApplyChanges`:

```
context.Attachments.ApplyChanges(att);
if (context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(att).State == EntityState.Deleted)
{
    var data = new AttachmentData() {Id = att.Id};
    context.AttachmentDataSet.Attach(data);
    context.AttachmentDataSet.DeleteObject(data);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is what baffles me profoundly: why can't EF figure out that, since the entities are stored in the same table, deleting one of them will also delete the other? Why do you need to load it?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: I guess because nobody has implemented that feature yet.