# Entity Framework Saving One to One relation in Table Splitting

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

For the sake of performance, I have decided to split a table following [this technique](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef-table-splitting-ndash-the-opposite-of-entity-splitting/).
So basically I have a second entity in order to hold a binary field.
These are my classes:

```
public partial class CustomerDoc
{
    public byte[] Document { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer customer { get; set; }
}

public partial class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerDoc CustomerDoc { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I try to update the Document property in an existing Customer instance with the file uploaded, this value is not saved in the database, other properties are saved but not Document.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(Customer customer, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //code to modify other properties 

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes((int)file.InputStream.Length);

                customer.CustomerDoc= new CustomerDoc { CustomerID = customer.CustomerID, Document = binData };

            }

            db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
         }
```

I've checked that other properties are modified correctly.

CustomerDoc have a value after SaveChanges call, but is not saved on database.

Also I've tried to update in a second instance of the same customer inside of the IF statement, but the I get a bunch of errors

This is the Mapping Detail:

```
Mapping Details - CustomerDoc
  Maps to Customer
    Column Mapping
       CustomerID : int <-> *CustomerID : Int32
       Document : varbinary(max) <-> Document: Binary
```

Comment: Did you make proper association? Can you post your Model configuration?

Comment: Is CustomerID in CustomerDoc primary key?

Comment: Yes, it's marked as Entity Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to save the customerDoc entity independently from customer.

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
    byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes((int)file.InputStream.Length);

    var customerDoc = new CustomerDoc { CustomerID = customer.CustomerID, Document = binData };
    db.Entry(customerDoc).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the inner if block in your code with the following:

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
    byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes((int)file.InputStream.Length);

    var customerDoc = new CustomerDoc { CustomerID = customer.CustomerID, Document = binData };
    db.Set<CustomerDoc>().Add(customerDoc);
}
```

Comment: Throw this error: "Invalid data encountered. A required relationship is missing. Examine StateEntries to determine the source of the constraint violation."

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170975/entity-framework-split-table-delete