# Entity Framework error deleting split table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to delete a row from the database which has a split table assoicated with it, however, I cannot seem to delete the split table relationship.

Here is the code I am trying to execute

```
  public void DeleteProductItemSplit(ProductItem pi)
  {
     // ProductItemData is the split table
     var data = new ProductItemData() { Id = pi.Id };

     m_Context.ProductItemData.Attach(data);

     m_Context.ProductItemData.Remove(data);
  }
```

On the second line

```
     m_Context.ProductItemData.Attach(data);
```

I get this error

> Additional information: Multiplicity constraint violated. The role
>   'ProductItem_Data_Target' of the relationship
>   'UpdaterDataLayer.ProductItem_Data' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

If I ignore the attach line, then I get this error when trying to remove the object

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager.

Any ideas on how to solve?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to attach and then remove the product.??

Comment: I am trying to follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170975/entity-framework-split-table-delete

so no I just want it to be deleted

Comment: Is `pi` in the context?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete it just use this:

```
public void DeleteProductItemSplit(ProductItem pi)
{
    m_Context.ProductItemData.Remove(m_Context.ProductItemData.Find(pi.Id));
}
```

Find allows you to easily get element by primary key. The on resulting entity you may invoke Remove to finally delete it.